# Use docker in one step of the Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have a jenkins master and some slaves. All on their own servers.
Now we have installed Docker on the slaves. We try to create a very basic pipeline now which will perform one step in the container.

I saw configurations where the agent is a docker container. 
But we want something like this:

```
    pipeline {
        agent any

        triggers {
            pollSCM pipelineParams.polling
        }

        options {
            buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '3'))
        }

        stages {
            stage('Clone') {
                steps {
                    //clone repo scm..
                }
            }

            stage ('npm') {
                steps {
                    script {
                        sh 'npm ...'
                }
            }
            stage ('docker') {
                steps {
                    //start docker container and mount project in it
                }
            }
            ...
```

How do we have to configure the docker step? Do we have to define a new agent insdie the stage step while we have agent any already above?

Comment: You can have multiple agents so that one stage is in docker and the rest are outside it.

Comment: Why not `agent { label 'docker' }` instead of the top `agent any`?